# How to make all images clickable? (In posts WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, function

When I first created my site, I automatically made sure that all images had no links (`image_default_link_type = none`). Now I’ve done Lightbox, so I need to make all the images in all the posts clickable.

I need to translate all the images in all posts from the view:

```
<img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Apple-iPhone-6-0.jpg" alt="" width="1500" height="1000" />
```

at

```
<a href="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Apple-iPhone-6-0.jpg"> <img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Apple-iPhone-6-0.jpg" alt="" width="1500" height="1000" /> </a>
```

How can I do that?

There is a function:

```
add_filter ('the_content', 'del_image_link');
function del_image_link ($ content) {
  $ content =
  preg_replace (array ('{a [^&gt;] *&gt; &lt;img}', '{/&gt; </a>}'), array ('&lt;img', '/&gt;'), $ content);
  return $ content;
}
```

It works in reverse order, that is, it makes absolutely all images with links non-sticky. I need to achieve the opposite effect.

Comment: You can do it with jQuery. Have you tried it?

Comment: Unfortunately, my jQuery skills are not so good to do that. So I did not try.

Comment: Check my answer below you can add that script in footer. Let me know if it works for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").each(function() {
     $(this).wrap("<a href="+$(this).attr('src')+"></a>");
  });
});
```

You can add this script in footer and on document ready you can loop through all `img` elements. In that loop using jQuery [WRAP](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) you can wrap the `img` tag with `a` tag.

Comment: Your code works, but not how I need it.

It effectively substitutes links to all publications, making them clickable, but in this case they do not add a special attribute from the plug-in for the Lightbox.

Comment: Which plug-in are you using?@SergDu5

Comment: Responsive Lightbox от dFactory
https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-lightbox/

Comment: Check if your script is getting added after lightbox js? @SergDu5

Comment: Yes, it is added after Lightbox.

Comment: Add it before lightbox JS please and check if it works? @SergDu5

Answer (score 0):

```
#Using the code in the functions.php with the following: # 

<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large' );
    echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '">';
    the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );
    echo '</a>';
}
?>

#  OR  #
# Link all post thumbnails to the post permalink #   
<?php    
        function wpdocs_post_image_html( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) {
            $html = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( get_the_title( $post_id ) ) . '">' . $html . '</a>';
            return $html;
        }
        add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'wpdocs_post_image_html', 10, 3 );
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this code needs to be pasted into Functions?

Comment: And further. I mean not miniatures of records, but images in articles (in news, reviews, interviews, etc.)

Comment: Yes, all post thumbnails to the post permalink